# Laravel 5.3 - Add some logic after each user login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm almost sure there's a way to do this, but after some searching in documentation without any solution I have to ask here. I need to add some logic after a user is successfully login (attach a variable to current session). I'm using the pre built Authentication Laravel module. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events). cntrl +f **login**. The first example is literally how to attach to  the `user login event`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It works fine! Could you post your answer in order to mark it as solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your home method, like so:

```
public function home(Request $request)
{
   $request->session()->put('variable_name', $variable_value);
}
```